# Link one page to another in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

this is supposed to be simple
i have two pages A and B what i want to do is add a button (a hyperlink or image will do) in page A that when clicked go to page B

how can i do that ?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways.  Perhaps the simplest is to create an Apex button using the Create Button wizard.  Follow the instructions and when you get to the "Action When Clicked" page, choose "Redirect to Page in this Application" as the Action and enter the Page number you want to go to when the button is clicked.  You can also enter other details such as Request, Clear Cache, Set These Items.
[image]

Comment: the action when clicked part is not visible on any button that i create , it is only found in the button that is generated by apex

Comment: ok solved , the answer was to choose "create a region button" not just "create a button" and setting the authentication option of this page to public , thanks

Comment: @Ahmed, opening the authentication to public shouldn't be required to have a navigation button.

Comment: without setting this option of the destination page ,the application kept redirecting me to the login page again

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want a button, simply use a html href to `f?p=&APP_ID.:<your page number to link to>:&SESSION`.

`<a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:2:&SESSION.">Go to page 2!</a>` takes you to your page number 2...